# How should redirects be handled with django-pjax?

Tags: django, pjax

I'm using [django-pjax](https://github.com/jacobian/django-pjax), and I'm not sure how I should be redirecting from within a view that could also return a pjax response.

If I use the redirect shortcut, I get:

```
AttributeError: 'HttpResponseRedirect' object has no attribute 'template_name'
```

Probably because django-pjax requres a TemplateResponse object, not a HttpResponse object.
But since TemplateResponse objects don't handle redirects, I'm not sure what to do.

Any guidance is appreciated!

Comment: Are you trying to send the browser to a completely new URL? Or load content located at the redirected url using pjax?

You might have to skip using the decorator for these views.

Answer (score 0):

At your front-end try this type of redirecting:

```
$.pjax({url: $('.logo').attr('href'), container: '#w0'});
```

Replace $('.logo').attr('href') to your url and #w0 to your container ID.